# Retry request using retry-axios for 401 error is going into infinite loop

Tags: typescript, axios, retry-axios

I am using `axios` to make requests for and for 401 error I am using `retry-axios` module to retry the request for 3 times. But its going into a infinite loop and its causing high alert.
This is the code I have written:

```
 private registerInterceptors() {
        this.httpClient.defaults.raxConfig = {
            backoffType: 'static',
            httpMethodsToRetry: ['GET', 'POST'],
            instance: this.httpClient,
            onRetryAttempt: async (err: AxiosError) => {
                const currentRetryAttempt = err.config?.raxConfig?.currentRetryAttempt ?? 0;
                const maxRetries = err.config?.raxConfig?.retry ?? 0;
                if (currentRetryAttempt >= maxRetries) {
                    // Do not retry if the maximum limit is reached
                    throw new Error('Exceeded maximum retry attempts');
                }
                await this.authStrategy.getNewToken();
            },
            retry: 3,
            retryDelay: 100,
            statusCodesToRetry: [[401, 401]],
        };
        rax.attach(this.httpClient);
        this.httpClient.interceptors.response.use(response => response, (error) => {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
    }
```

I am calling the method registerInterceptors in the constructor:

```
constructor(
        @inject(TfInjectionKeys.HttpClient) private httpClient: AxiosInstance,
        ......
    ) {
        this.registerInterceptors();
    }
```

Now everytime the code goes into `onRetryAttempt` function the `currentRetryAttempt` is always 1 and it goes into a infinite loop. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to retry a request for 3 times if statuscode is 401. If it still fails it should throw the error.